# Sort Markdown file by heading

Tags: sorting, sed, markdown

Is it possible to sort a markdown file by level 1 heading? Looking for `sed` or similar command line solution

```
#B
a content of B

#A
b content of A
```

to...

```
#A
b content of A

#B
a content of B
```

Comment: Sed or awk should be feasible. But a more structured way would be to parse it and restructure it. E.g., [this](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/) seems to be a python library that understands and parses markdown documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A perl one-liner, split for readability

```
perl -0777 -ne '
    (undef,@paragraphs) = split /^#(?=[^#])/m; 
    print map {"#$_"} sort @paragraphs;
' file.md
```

You'll want to end the file with a blank line, so there's a blank line before `#B`. Or you could change
`map {"#$_"}` to `map {"#$_\n"}`
 to forcibly insert one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GNU Awk with `PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"`:

```
gawk 'BEGIN { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"; RS = ""; ORS = "\n\n" }
      { a[$1] = $0 } END { for (i in a) print a[i] }' file
```

Output:

```
#A
b content of A

#B
a content of B
```

Reference:

> ```
> PROCINFO["sorted_in"]
>
>    If this element exists in PROCINFO,
>    then its value controls the order in
>    which array elements are traversed in
>    for loops.  Supported values are
>    "@ind_str_asc", "@ind_num_asc",
>    "@val_type_asc", "@val_str_asc",
>    "@val_num_asc", "@ind_str_desc",
>    "@ind_num_desc", "@val_type_desc",
>    "@val_str_desc", "@val_num_desc", and
>    "@unsorted".  The value can also be the
>    name of any comparison function defined
>    as follows:
> ```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this script to have the sorting on 3 levels instead of just one. It also won't stripe out the content before the first occurence of the first heading.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

local $/;
my $text = <>;
my ($start, @chapters) = split/^#(?=[^#])/m, $text;
print $start;
for (sort @chapters) {
    my ($level1, @subchapters) = split/^##(?=[^#])/m;
    print "#$level1";
        for (sort @subchapters) {
        my ($level2, @subsubchapters) = split/^###(?=[^#])/m;
        print "##$level2";
        print map {"###$_"} sort @subsubchapters; 
        }
}
```